# Blazor parameters in root page not working in Azure Static Web Apps

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

I have a Blazor wasm project I am working on and I have the following functionality:

- When a user arrives to **mydomain.com/customer** they are redirected to the customer details
- As expected, all this functionality comes from an API and the list of customers is dynamic therefore I am not designing a custom page per customer. I - instead - have one page to accomplish that

In my code I use the following logic:

1. When a user types mydomain.com/ I display the list of all available customers
2. If a user navigates to mydomain.com/customer, my Index.razor page will not display the list of customers but instead display the customer detail
3. In the first case where a list of customers is displayed, when a user clicks on a customer, I use the NavigationManager to navigate to "/customer". This works great!

When I am running the application on my local machine, if I directly point to the URL for https://localhost:port/customer I am directed to the customer page.

In essence, everything happens on the root page (Index.razor). I understand that I can maybe redirect to https://localhost:port/c/customer to avoid using the root but I am not even sure if that is really my issue and I would like to avoid it if I can use something more elegant like the solution I have above which works locally on my machine.

Once I deployed this to Azure Static Web Apps I get 404 error if I attempt to directly go to the https://azure-static-apps-page/customer. I do not get an error if I attempt to go to the root page and then click on a customer on the list.

I suspect once it's published in Azure I am missing some configuration.

In case it helps, I do have `<base href="/" />` in my index.html

Can someone assist so that I can understand why this is happening?

My Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@page "/{CustomerURL}"

@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

@if(string.isNullOrEmpty(CustomerURL)
{
  // Display list of customers (display a component)
} else
{
  // Display specific customer details (display a component)
  if(customer != null)
  {
    // Display customer details
  } else {
    <h3>Customer does not exist</h3>
  }
}
```

The parameter & Customer object:

```
[Parameter]
public string? Customer { get; set; }

private Customer customer;
```

My OnInitializedAsync:

```
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   // If the parameter is not null, call the API to find the customer
   customer = APICall();
}
```

My SetParametersAsync:

```
public async override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
{
    await base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
    customer = APICall();
}
```

My OnClick method for when a customer is selected:

```
public void OnCustomerSelected(Customer c)
{
    // This is where the URL changes from https://localhost:port to https://localhost:port/customer
    navigationManager.NavigateTo("/" + c.CustomerUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static web apps do not have a typical web server, so you have to configure a fallback route

[Docs: Fallback route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-blazor#fallback-route)

> ## Fallback route
>
> The application exposes URLs like /counter and
> /fetchdata which map to specific routes of the application. Since this
> app is implemented as a single page application, each route is served
> the index.html file. To ensure that requests for any path return
> index.html a fallback route is implemented in the
> **staticwebapp.config.json** file found in the Client project's **root
> folder.**

```json
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to match the names exactly

```html
@page "/"
@page "/{CustomerURL}"
```

...

```cs
  [Parameter]
//public string? Customer { get; set; }
  public string? CustomerURL { get; set; }
```

Comment: My apologies my friend I was renaming the parameters so as not to give away some of the specifics of the web app and I mistyped the parameter. Unfortunately that is not the issue. Thank you, your time is appreciated.